# Hadoop processing time in datanode

Tags: java, hadoop, cpu

I have two questions here:

1. I have 1x master and 1 node setup and process a file of 5MB. I found the total processing time is almost same as below with or without the datanode. I am referring to CPU time spent which almost 6 seconds. Anyone can reply here that the datanode is actually doing the job?

   How can I monitor that?

   ```
   Map input records=1
               Map output records=802685
               Map output bytes=8428185
               Map output materialized bytes=10033561
               Input split bytes=97
               Combine input records=0
               Combine output records=0
               Reduce input groups=3
               Reduce shuffle bytes=10033561
               Reduce input records=802685
               Reduce output records=3
               Spilled Records=1605370
               Shuffled Maps =1
               Failed Shuffles=0
               Merged Map outputs=1
               GC time elapsed (ms)=527
               CPU time spent (ms)=5800
               Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=550604800
               Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=5864865792
               Total committed heap usage (bytes)=421007360
               Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=416796672
               Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=2929139712
               Peak Reduce Physical memory (bytes)=133808128
               Peak Reduce Virtual memory (bytes)=2935726080
   ```
2. I faced out of memory error when running a file size of 20MB. I have set 4GB for this processing. Wondering why does this hadoop consumes so much of resources.

   It's just a map reduce job as the simple text below and produce an output of the count of below.

   ```
   ,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,TrainBUS,car,
   ```

Does anybody has an answer?